# How can i include my certificate chain and private key in a tls server using openssl library?

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, sslserversocket

I am trying to write a c code to implement a tls socket using openssl. The server has a certificate chain with 4 certificates:
leaf certificate - intermediate1 certificate -intermediate2 certificate - root certificate
I init everything in the order:

```
SSL_library_init()
SSL_load_error_strings()         
OpenSSL_add_ssl_algorithms()
```

When ctx config is:

```
SSL_ctx_set_cipher_list()
SSL_ctx_use_certificate_chain("",pem)
SSL_ctx_use_certificate_file("",pem)      (1)
SSL_ctx_use_PrivateKey(".key",pem)
```

I get the error "unknown ca" which is guess because calling SSL_ctx_use_certificate_file discards SL_ctx_use_certificate_chain and thus, the client cannot verify the server certificate.
When ctx config is:

```
SSL_ctx_set_cipher_list()
SSL_ctx_use_certificate_chain("",pem)  (2)
SSL_ctx_use_PrivateKey(".key",pem)
```

I get a certificate-key mismatch error.
I formed the chain using:

```
cat server.pem intermediate1.pem intermediate2.pem > chain.pem
```

so i haven't included the root certificate in the chain since the client already has it.
I would expect (2) to work since the private key is the key corresponding to the server.pem certificate which is at the top of the chain.

-How should i include the chain in the c code in a way that i don't get a key-cert. mismatch error?
I found a this function:

```
SSL_CTX_add_extra_chain_cert()
```

but i could not understand how to use it. The second argument of this function is X509* so how should i load and input it to this function.
-Is there a function in openssl that loads the certificate from memory? Note that my certificates are all in pem format and this X509 confuses me since i am not really familiar with cert. data types.
-Do i need to use

```
SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations()
```

function on the server side if i am not asking the client for its certificates?

EDIT:

```
SSL *ssl;
SSL_CTX *ctx;

void configure_context(SSL_CTX *ctx)
{
   if(SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx,CIPHER_LIST) <= 0)
   {
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
   }
   
   if(SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(ctx,"/var/lib/certs/chain.pem") <= 0)
   {
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
   }

   if (SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, "/var/lib/certs/private.key", X509_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0 ) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
   }
}

bool sslAcceptSocket()
{
    SSL_library_init();
    init_openssl();
    ctx = create_context();

    configure_context(ctx);
    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);

    SSL_set_fd(ssl, acceptedSocket);
    static int err = 0;
    err = SSL_accept(ssl);
    if(err < 1)
    {
    DEBUG_PRINT("SSL Error: %d\n",err);
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

acceptedSocket is the TCP socket and it works fine. However, i get key-cert mismatch error in the tls part.
Replacing

```
SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(ctx,"/var/lib/certs/chain.pem")
```

with

```
SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx,"/var/lib/certs/leaf.pem")
```

solves the key-cert. mismatch problem but then i get "unknown ca" error (as expected)

Comment: There is no `SSL_ctx_use_certificate_chain`. Did you mean `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file`?  Also the arguments for the functions don't really match. Please provide a minimal but working example so that one can reproduce your problem instead of some code snippets which are wrong and would not even compile. But in general: `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file` together with `SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey` should work when properly done. `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` on the server is only needed for validating client certificates on the server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to the certificates and the key so the code in the "EDIT" part of the question actually works with the correct certificates.